# Процессы в linux на с++

Tags: c++, linux

Здравствуйте. Столкнулся с необходимостью создания дочерних процессов в linux. Использую функцию fork(), которая возвращает pid дочернего процесса. Можно ли создать дочерний процесс и открыть его в новом окне терминала средствами языка С++? Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Зависит от того, что именно Вы хотите сделать.

1. Можно запустить терминал (эмулятор терминала, например xterm) и в уже в нем новую программу. Аналогично запуску из командной строки : xterm -e more /etc/passwd.
   Для запуска xterm используете fork() и затем например execl(), а в параметрах передаете путь к исполняемой в терминале программе и ее параметры.
2. Если Вы хотите напрямую подсоединить к новому терминалу только что созданный fork-ом процесс, то сразу не соображу, как это сделать.

Видимо надо внимательно изучать man-ы для "терминалов". По сути требуется, чтобы pty, создаваемый эмулятором оказался соединен с открытыми в дочернем процессе файловыми дескрипторами.

На самом деле интересная задачка. Плюсую.

---

Придумал. Но довольно уродливый вариант.

Запускаем (fork/exec) эмулятор. Под ним запускаем нашу (заранее написанную) программу, которая читает stdin и пишет в stdout, связанные с этим эмулятором, а пару других дескрипторов открывает на имя переданного ей как параметр fifo файла. Работаем с этим хозяйством через select().

В этот же fifo-файл пишет-читает Ваш дочерний процесс. Fifo (вызов mkfifo()) видимо должен делать родитель, который запустит затем эмулятор и собственно Ваш дочерний процесс.

В результате набираемый на клавиатуре в окошке эмулятора текст может быть прочитан Вашим процессом, а его запись в fifo попадет в это окошко. Моделирование сигналов и особенно закрытие входного потока - это здесь особая песня (в общем случае непростая).

Что-то в таком духе.

---

**UPDATE 2**

Еще одно решение. Если Вам для порождаемого процесса нужно окно ввода-вывода, то посмотрите на **putty**.

Идея состоит в следующем. Подготавливаете серверный (для которого вызывают accept()) сокет на localhost и запускаете (через fork/exec) putty c host/port Вашего сокета.

Общаетесь с окошком по этому сокету в любых Ваших процессах. IMHO нормально будет работать.

Answer (score 2):

В С++ можно использовать все системные вызовы и функции, поставляемые библиотекой libc, в том числе и fork.

Comment: А возможно ли сделать так, чтобы при создании дочернего процесса он открывался в новом окне терминала?

Comment: Процесс, создаваем форком, связан с тем же терминалом, что и родительский процесс. Можно далее запустить exec'ом gnome-terminal (например) и ему передать в качестве параметра запускаемый файл.